# accessing apache webpage from external location

Tags: apache2

I'm trying to configure multiple websites on my locally installed ubuntu server(v 14.10) and the problem im having is accessing a web page i create ie testing.dev from outside my local environment. side note, the domains that im setting up are for personal use only.

Ubuntu/apache default webpage works.
newly created domain/site: www.testing.dev page works

the default webpag has the link to www.testing.dev web site ie. 
[testing](http://www.testing.dev)
and this works if i access it through the local network but not from a external location ie coffee ship.

both sites work if i access it from local device(internal network).
The default webpage also works if i tried accessing it from a device outside my network example coffee shop but when i click the link to www.testing.dev i get the message Server not found page.

the log files or the access files seem to capture the problem.

any ideas as to what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt that you own the domain name "testing.dev" (.dev domains don't exist *yet*) so what is the reasoning here?  Why are you using that name and how did you set it up to work locally?

In order for your website to be reachable under a domain name on the internet, as opposed to a bare IP address, you need to:

- Register a domain name with a registry.
- Set up your own nameservers (complex) or set up your domain registry's nameservers (simple, assuming the registrar supports it) to point that domain name at your IP address.
- Set up your web server to respond to that name (virtual hosting) or IP address.

Comment: Hello,

This is just an internal server setup to learn web programming and looking to create a environment close to the real world. I'm use xxxx.dlinkddns.com to connect to my webserver more specifically to the default webpage(ubuntu apache2).. and on the default webpage i'm going to add internal webpages example www.testing.dev, www.testing2.dev etc. to test my scripts. this will not be published to the internet by any means.

Comment: Your question asked how to connect to the site "from a device outside my network example coffee shop".  How is a device on another network (like a coffee shop) going to be able to access your site if it's "not published to the internet by any means"???  This doesn't make any sense.